# Do cities only follow the dominant religion in Civilisation V?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

What happens if my city has 3 religions, does it benefit from all of the follower beliefs, or does it just work for the current most dominant religion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It only gets the benefit from the current most-dominant religion in the city. The rest of the religions in your cities are, obviously, heretics and infidels. (Just ask the dominant religion!)

I've seen this in the *Into The Renaissance* scenario, where the Catholics can buy troops with faith; you can't buy troops unless Catholicism is the *dominant* religion.

As of the *Brave New World* expansion, there is now a policy in the Piety culture tree to grant the Pantheon bonus of the second-most-popular religion in your cities. Pantheon bonuses are pretty small, but it *is* something from a non-dominant religion in your city.